# Axes tick labelling after using imagesc in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I am trying to plot a 512*512 matrix with specified axes values. This is the code I am using but somehow the returned figure still shows the axes labelled as 512 * 512.

```
x = [0,1];
y = [0,100];
X = reshape(prob_to_1,512,512);
colormap('hot');
figure;
subplot(1,1,1);
axis([0 1 0 100]);
imagesc(X);
```

I want the final figure to be labelled between 0-1 on y-axes and between 0-100 on the x-axes.

Any suggestions/ideas?

Thanks!!

Comment: The code example is not good. The first two lines are not needed because variables `x`and `y` are not used. `subplot(1,1,1)` is also not necessary and `axis(..)` has no effect because it comes before `imagesc`. If it came after it would actually change the part of the data that is shown, so better not using it at all here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unfortunately you cannot do it directly but have to set custom tick labels like this:

```
X = magic(512); % just some test data
imagesc(X);
set(gca, 'XTick', [0:0.1:1]*512, 'XTickLabel', [0:0.1:1]*100) % 10 ticks 
set(gca, 'YTick', [0:0.05:1]*512, 'YTickLabel', [0:0.05:1]) % 20 ticks
```

Adjust the spacing of the ticks to change the number of ticks accordingly.

Comment: So this still preserves the final matrix which is output as 512*512 matrix with the x and y-axes labelled between (0,1) and (0,100) respectively?

Comment: Yes, just try it out and hopefully you'll see it.

Comment: @KashifNawaz When you have tested it and it works it would be nice if you could mark the answer as accepted. :)

Comment: it doesnt seem to work..:( the problem i think is the set(..) code is multiplying the individual probabilities in my X matrix by 512 and making them all close to zero;so in effect I'm getting a heatmap which shows that all my values are concentrated close to 0 on the x-axes!!

Comment: That should not be the case. The setting of x- and y- labels should not multiply the image data. At least for me it doesn't.

Comment: Why do you want to overcome this? It makes a 2D array out of linear data. I thought that's what you want. Anyway my guess is that the question is now another. If you execute the example in my answer you see that I can label axes arbitrarily and this should solve the question. Now you seem to have another problem. You could make another question out of it.

Comment: Well @Trilarion: Its done!! Thanks..I think now i can manipulate the rest!! Thanks a lot for ur quick replies!! :)